# Tkinter flash window in taskbar

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4, taskbar

How can I make the taskbar icon flash orange in a tkinter application?
This would preferably be for python 3.4.
There is a screenshot in an unrelated post here:
http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/265769-win7-how-change-default-orange-blinking-icon-taskbar.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python-Tkinter:how to highlight item on taskbar on windows xp when window is minimized to the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478279/python-tkinterhow-to-highlight-item-on-taskbar-on-windows-xp-when-window-is-min)